# How to programatically add row w/ label to declarative dojox.layout.TableContainer (Dojo 1.6)

Tags: dojo

The TableContainer is declared in HTML like so:

```
<div dojoType="dojox.layout.TableContainer" jsId="myTable" id="myTable" cols="1">
    <!-- stuff -->     
</div>
```

I tried adding a row containing a TextBox programmatically like so:

```
var tb = new dijit.form.TextBox({
            label: "Name"
        });
myTable.addChild(tb);
```

The TextBox will be displayed below the table and no labels are shown. How can I place new rows with label inside the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah there is some issue with tablecontainer ,the suggested work around for this issue would be

```
<div id='myTable'></div>
```

declare the div in the HTML but convert it into tableContainer in script then u can have the use of both the ways avoiding the bug

initialize the table container in script like

`var myTable=new dojox.layout.TableCOntainer({cols:1},"myTable");`

```
don't forget to startup our table container after adding the childrens
```

After this  you can easily add any number of childs normally

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug. It looks like once the TableContainer has been started the first time, adding children wont trigger a new `layout()` etc. A quick but hideous workaround would be to make the TableContainer "forget" that it has already been initialized and started, and then run `startup()` manually.

```
var tb = new dijit.form.TextBox({
            label: "Name"
        });
myTable.addChild(tb);

myTable._initialized = false;
myTable._started = false;
myTable.startup();
```

I take no responsibility for any unforeseen oddities this may cause though :-) Normally manipulating private members (the ones starting with an underscore) is a bad idea.